# Why does the comparator on a PIC microcontroller continually generate interrupts

Tags: comparator, pic, microchip, adc

I am trying to use the two comparator modules on a PIC18F46K22 and one of the comparators is continually generating an interrupt.

The idea is to wake the program on change of an analogue input. Two DACs provide reference values which are slightly higher and slightly lower than the analogue input value. These are connected to the positive pins of the comparators. The analogue input is the negative pin.

When an interrupt from the comparator occurs in the interrupt routine I disable the comparator module and the comparator interrupt and clear the interrupt flag.

In my main line I sample the analogue, output values to two reference DACs and then re-enable the comparator and the comparator interrupt.

The problem is that every time I do this the comparator immediately generates an interrupt so the program never sleeps. I tried increasing the reference value from the DAC but still the interrupt still occurs.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: The problem was being casued by a spurious interrupt being generated when the comparator module is enabled. 
I solved this by including a delay between enabling the comparator, and enabling the comparator input (as per PIC18(L)F2X/4XK22 data sheet DS41412F-page 314 Note 2).
There was also some issues caused by input voltage instability which I have resolved by changing the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem once. If you are checking the comparator interrupt with the interrupt flag like: `if(pir1.cmif==1){....}` interrupt continue to occurs. I used comparator output states to check it in interrupt routine like: `if(cmcon0.cout==1){...}else{...}`. This was useful for me (the pic was 12f683 by the way registers might be different).